# remove term from custom taxonomy list

Tags: custom-taxonomy, exclude

I have the terms of a custom taxonomy presented in a list like this:

```
        <?php $taxonomy = 'categories'; $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy); ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
        }?></ul>
```

There are a number of terms to this taxonomy (print, digital, type, etc...) however, one of them, called "archive", id like to not display in this list. Is there any way to exclude it from the above code?

Answer (score 1):

`get_terms()` got an upgrade in WordPress v4.6 so you can use the news `WP_Term_Query` class instead. You can use this to simply exclude the ID of the term `archive` so that it never becomes part of your results to begin with. So say the ID of `archive` is 5:

```
$args = array(
   'taxonomy' => 'category',
   'exclude'  => 5,
);
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
if ( ! empty( $term_query->terms ) ) {
   foreach (  $term_query->terms as term ) {
      // What you want it to do
   }
} else {
   echo 'Term Not Found';
}
```

The `'exclude'` argument can be an array too so if you wanted to exclude IDs 5, 10, and 15 you just replace `5` with `array( 5, 10, 15 ),`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'categories';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term)
        if ('archive' !== $tax_term->name)
            echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, then either the term name is not _archive_, or I didn't understand what you wanted in the first place. Have you tried debugging (i.e., `echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_terms('categories'), true).'</pre>';`)?

Comment: The name is case sensitive and such. So `Archive`, `archive`, `archivE` would all be three different values. Try targeting `$tax_term->slug` instead.